# VBA Sum with 2 condition

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

```
Sub Tsum()
Dim int001 As Range
Dim int002 As Range
Dim int003 As Range
   Dim data1 As Date
    Dim data2 As Date
    Dim data3 As Date
Dim dates As Date
Dim nr_rows As Integer

'--------------------------------------------------------------

nr_rows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set int001 = Range("B2:B" & nr_rows)
Set int002 = Range("C2:C" & nr_rows)
Set int003 = Range("D2:D" & nr_rows)
    data1 = "01/02/2016"
    data2 = "02/02/2016"
    data3 = "03/02/2016"
Set dates = Range("A2:A" & nr_rows)
'--------------------------------------------------------------

Range("H2:H" & nr_rows) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(dates, Range("B2:B" & nr_rows), data1 & data2 & data3, Range("B2:B" & nr_rows), ">0")


End Sub
```

I need a little help with vba.

I have only the table "A1:D10", and I made the column "H" to understand what results i want.

So, the sum in column "H" is made from table "A1:D10" but it's necessary 2 condition:

- sum all the data from the column with the same date
- value from that column need to be > 0

And set this results in column "H" like in the picture.

Above I have tried to start the script but no results until now.

Comment: SUMIFS or an array formula could do this

Comment: You know you can do it with SUMIFs, but you don't know how?  Have you looked at the help for SUMIFs?

Answer (score 0):

SUMIFS or an array formula could do this `SUMIFS($B$1:$B$3,$A$1:$A$3,"01/02/2016",$B$1:$B$3,">0")` for example

Comment: Yes, but you can fill down and use OFFSET, to move the SUM column based on the day, look at SUMIFs and OFFSET help, you'll find the solution in there.

Comment: I want to do it, in VBA not in Excel

Comment: Well how are you doing SUM in VBA, come one, have a go yourself.  You can use functions like OFFSET in VBA to.

Comment: youre not defining your ranges properly Range("A2" & A &     nr_rows) should be Range("A2:A"&     nr_rows)

Comment: you need to loop the rows, and set your columns, have you looked at how sumifs works?  your effort doesn't show that you have, not set like that.   I am not doing your work for you, just saying "doesn't work", shows 0 effort on your part.  Learn SUMIFS, do it on the sheet, then code around what you want.  It would have taken less time to learn and understand SUMIFS, that running back and forth on this.

Comment: Today is the first time when i use VBA and that why i'm   a little amateur. I need to do this for a project. Anyway thank you for your advice. I will try to solve this problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use formula for this.

I'm assuming that the size of the table will increase as extra days are added and that this table will not have any blank rows in column A and there will be no extra data below the table.

First thing is to set up a formula to take this into account:

Create a named range using this formula: `=Sheet1!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))`
Make sure you include the sheet name in the formula.  I've called this range `ReportDates`.

In ***Excel 2007+*** you can then use:
`=SUMIFS(OFFSET(ReportDates,,1),ReportDates,DATEVALUE("01-Feb-2016"),OFFSET(ReportDates,,1),">0")`

or you could set up named ranges for **int001**... **int003** (int001 is an invalid named range though, so you can't name it that - I've used **into001**
`=Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))`  (note I'm still counting column A).

Your formula would then be:
`=SUMIFS(into001,ReportDates,DATEVALUE("01-Feb-2016"),into001,">0")`

If you're using ***Excel 2003*** you can use:
`=SUMPRODUCT((ReportDates=DATEVALUE("01-Feb-2016"))*(into001>=0)*into001)`
or
`=SUMPRODUCT((ReportDates=DATEVALUE("01-Feb-2016"))*(OFFSET(ReportDates,,1)>=0)*OFFSET(ReportDates,,1))`

Comment: How can i set a variable for month(1-12) and another for day(1-31) to use it, for automate the proces when appear the "date" condition.

Comment: How do i implement this in VBA?

Comment: Without using VBA you could type the date into cell F2 - 01/02/2016 and give it a custom number format of `"Day" d` - this will then display "Day 1".  Your formula in H2 could then be: `=SUMIFS(into001,ReportDates,F2,into001,">0")`, H3 and H4 could use into002 and into003.  Then just copy those three formula and paste for each day.  Can't see a reason for VBA...